# Select rows by multiple conditions and columns

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, conditional-statements

I have large data frame with different groups:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Week=c("Week1", "Week1","Week1","Week1","Week1","Week1","Week1","Week1","Week1","Week1","Week1","Week1"),
  Day = c("Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday",
          "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Thursday"),
  Type=c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C","A", "B", "C" ),
  Result=c("YES", "YES", "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO", "YES", "NO", "NO","YES", "YES", "NO")
```

[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPQao.png)

I would like to add another column that indicates a "YES" for the weekday that had the result "YES" for both type "A" AND "B", so like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  Week=c("Week1", "Week1","Week1","Week1","Week1","Week1","Week1","Week1","Week1","Week1","Week1","Week1"),
  Day = c("Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday",
          "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Thursday"),
  Type=c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C","A", "B", "C" ),
  Result=c("YES", "YES", "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO", "YES", "NO", "NO","YES", "YES", "NO"),
  Result.AB=c("YES", "YES", "YES", "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO","YES", "YES", "YES")

  )
```

[df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWTkf.png)
Could someone help me? Thank you =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using the tidyverse.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  Week=c("Week1", "Week1","Week1","Week1","Week1","Week1","Week1","Week1","Week1","Week1","Week1","Week1"),
  Day = c("Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday",
          "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Thursday"),
  Type=c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C","A", "B", "C" ),
  Result=c("YES", "YES", "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO", "YES", "NO", "NO","YES", "YES", "NO")
)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(Day = factor(Day, levels = c('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday'))) %>%
  spread(key = Type, value = Result) %>%
  mutate(Result.AB = ifelse(A == 'YES' & B == 'YES', 'YES', 'NO')) %>%
  gather(key = Type, value = Result, -c(Week, Day, Result.AB)) %>%
  arrange(Day, Type) %>%
  select(Week, Day, Type, Result, Result.AB)

df2
#>     Week       Day Type Result Result.AB
#> 1  Week1    Monday    A    YES       YES
#> 2  Week1    Monday    B    YES       YES
#> 3  Week1    Monday    C     NO       YES
#> 4  Week1   Tuesday    A     NO        NO
#> 5  Week1   Tuesday    B     NO        NO
#> 6  Week1   Tuesday    C     NO        NO
#> 7  Week1 Wednesday    A    YES        NO
#> 8  Week1 Wednesday    B     NO        NO
#> 9  Week1 Wednesday    C     NO        NO
#> 10 Week1  Thursday    A    YES       YES
#> 11 Week1  Thursday    B    YES       YES
#> 12 Week1  Thursday    C     NO       YES
```

I've used [`spread`](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/spread.html) to get one row per day, [`mutate`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html) to compute the new `Result.AB` variable then [`gather`](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/gather.html) to split up the observations again. The rest of the pipeline gets the rows into the right order.